# How to convert a hex value back to an ASCII string?

Tags: c#, arduino, hex, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to read from an accelerometer over BLE from my Arduino device. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to convert it back into a readable string value.

**My Arduino sketch (part of it)** looks like this:

```
if((x - lastX) > threshold) {
  STATUS = "MOVING";
  toggleIsMoving();
} else if((y - lastY) > threshold) {
  STATUS = "MOVING";
  toggleIsMoving();
} else if((z - lastZ) > threshold) {
  STATUS = "MOVING";
  toggleIsMoving();
} else {
  STATUS = "STOPPED";
  toggleIsStopped();
}
lastX = x;
lastY = y;
lastZ = z;
Serial.print(STATUS);
```

The hex value that I receive in my Xamarin Android application (through BLE) is this:

A0-08-00-00-00-4D-4F-56-49-4E-47-CE-3C

My current implementation is:

```
public static string FromHex(string hex) {
  hex = hex.Replace("-", "");
  byte[] raw = new byte[hex.Length / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < raw.Length; i++)
    raw[i] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
  return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(raw);
}
```

This result is:

?������MOVING?<

Why is this happening and how can I convert this back to a readable string in C#?

**Update 1**

I did some research in the bean-sdk source code and found this:

```
/**
   * Represents a LightBlue Serial Transport Message
   *
   * Defined as:
   *
   *    [1 byte]         - Length     (Message ID + Payload)
   *    [1 byte]         - Reserved
   *    [2 byte]      BE - Message ID
   *    [0-64 bytes]  LE - Payload
   *    [2 bytes]     LE - CRC        (Everything before CRC)
   *
   * @param messageId
   * @param definition
   */
```

**Update 2**

Finally got it working by implementing the protocol mentioned in update 1. The actual payload is located inside, so it needs to be extracted from the hex string.

Comment: the values A0-08-00-00-00 are outside the normal print range, so give you the wonky characters..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything over 0x7F is **NOT** ASCII. The first character is 0xA0. Which, both in Unicode and IOS LATIN 1 is NBSP. The sequence `A0-08-00-00-00` is probably meaningful, but not in a plain text way. You should have a look at the specs of your accelerometer and see what it is spewing out to interpret it correctly.

EDIT

Also, since in your code you set the variable `STATUS` to "MOVING", it could be that the characters before and after MOVING are spurious characters.

Comment: In this analysis, Unicode means the character set and you are using the UTF-8 encoding (`Encoding.UTF8`) for Unicode (as opposed to the UTF-16 encoding for Unicode `Encoding.Unicode`).

Comment: Ok, this is the board i'm using: https://punchthrough.com/bean/docs/guides/features/accelerometer/

Comment: Err no, there's no 0x00A0 in UTF-8. Latin 1's A0, UTF-16 0x00A0, is 0xC2A0 in UTF-8...

Comment: But good point about the confusion between Unicode and its encodings.

Comment: @dda Oops, you are correct about it not being UTF-8. Anyway, as you point out, it is probably not all text.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the following:

```
private static string hexToASCII(string hexValue)
{
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < hexValue.Length; i += 2)
    {
        string str = hexValue.Substring(i, 2);
        output.Append((char)Convert.ToInt32(str, 16));
    }
    return output.ToString();
}
```

Reference: converted from a Java function at [Convert Hex to ASCII and ASCII to Hex](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/string-class/convert-hex-to-ascii-and-ascii-to-hex/)

Comment: This code is using the ISO 8589-1 character set and its one encoding in a byzantine way. The first 256 codepoints of Unicode are the same as the entire ISO 8589-1 character set. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit. UTF-16 is an encoding of the Unicode character set. UTF-16 happens to encode the first 256 codepoints of Unicode using one 16-bit code unit with the high byte of 0. So, converting two hexadecimal digit characters to an integer and then casting to `char` effectively decodes the data as  ISO 8589-1 text.